# Function only get called, on window resize if wrapped in other function

Tags: jquery, function, resize

I have a function that centers a website vertically:

```
    function centerWebsite(){
        $vpheight = $(window).height();
        $headerheight = $('header').height();
        $contentheight = $headerheight + $('#content').height();
        $margin = Math.floor(($vpheight - $contentheight)/2);

        $logospacing = $('#logo').css('margin-top');

        if($vpheight > ($contentheight + $logospacing)) {
            $margin = $margin - $logospacing;
        }

        $extendedmargin = $headerheight + $margin;

        $('html').height($vpheight);
        $('body').height($vpheight);
        $('header').css('padding-top', $margin);
        $('#content').css('padding-top', $extendedmargin);
        $('#gallerynav').css('padding-top', $extendedmargin);
    }
```

This function should be called when the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(centerWebsite());
```

And every time the window gets resized I want to call the same function.
I tried to do it like this:

```
$(window).resize(centerWebsite());
```

But this won’t work. The solution to this was:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    centerWebsite();
});
```

Do I really need to create a function to call another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By including the parentheses, you're doing a function call. You're looking to pass the function as a reference, in which case, you should pass the variable - without the parentheses.

```
$(document).ready(centerWebsite);
```

If you add a console.log inside of your `centerwebsite()` function, you'll see that it was actually getting called when you called `$(document).ready(centerWebsite());`.

Answer (score 2):

remove parenthesis:

```
$(window).resize(centerWebsite);
```

EDIT NOTE: review this question for some information on callbacks: [What are jQuery hooks and callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735250/what-are-jquery-hooks-and-callbacks)